# Is it possible to render a non-4-sided container with HTML, CSS, and JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

TL;DR; Is it possible to have a non-square/4-sided HTML container?

I'm building a Tetris clone and I've finished building a function that will render the individual tetrominoes, however, as I'm thinking about how to build a "collision" or grid positioning system, I had a thought:

(ignore the margin in the images)

Is it possible to make a container like this (what we see everyday and all I've ever seen in my career):
[image: Typical container of a child elements]

have boundaries like this: (used Paint, so it's a bit meh)

[image]

Also, using JavaScript to build a game like this is something I'm very inexperienced with, so I believe this method of building and rendering the tetrominoes isn't going to work well, but I'd still be interested in my an answer to if my question is possible.

And, not that it's needed, but figured I'd share the CSS I'm using to render the style of the tetrominoes:

```
/* Sizes Variables */
:root {
  --tetromino-block-size: 30px;
}

.Tetromino {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-bottom: var(--tetromino-block-size);
  position: relative;
}

.Tetromino--grid {
  height: calc(var(--tetromino-block-size) * 2);
  width: 40px;
}

/* 1x4 */
.Tetromino--i {
  height: var(--tetromino-block-size);
  width: calc(var(--tetromino-block-size) * 4);
}

/* 3x2 */
.Tetromino--j {
  height: calc(var(--tetromino-block-size) * 2);
  width: calc(var(--tetromino-block-size) * 3);
}

/* 3x2 */
.Tetromino--l {
  height: calc(var(--tetromino-block-size) * 2);
  width: calc(var(--tetromino-block-size) * 3);
}

/* 2x2 */
.Tetromino--o {
  height: calc(var(--tetromino-block-size) * 2);
  width: calc(var(--tetromino-block-size) * 2);
}

/* 3x2 */
.Tetromino--s {
  height: calc(var(--tetromino-block-size) * 2);
  width: calc(var(--tetromino-block-size) * 3);
}

/* 3x2 */
.Tetromino--t {
  height: calc(var(--tetromino-block-size) * 2);
  width: calc(var(--tetromino-block-size) * 3);
}

/* 3x2 */
.Tetromino--z {
  height: calc(var(--tetromino-block-size) * 2);
  width: calc(var(--tetromino-block-size) * 3);
}

/* width: 9/10 variable block size; border: 1/10 variable block size */
.Tetromino__block {
  border: calc(var(--tetromino-block-size) / 10) inset black;
  height: calc(var(--tetromino-block-size) - calc(var(--tetromino-block-size) / 5));
  position: absolute;
  width: calc(var(--tetromino-block-size) - calc(var(--tetromino-block-size) / 5));
}

.Tetromino__block[quadrant=Q1A] {
  left: calc(var(--tetromino-block-size) * 2);
  top: 0;
}

.Tetromino__block[quadrant=Q1B] {
  left: calc(var(--tetromino-block-size) * 3);
  top: 0;
}

.Tetromino__block[quadrant=Q2A] {
  left: var(--tetromino-block-size);
  top: 0;
}

.Tetromino__block[quadrant=Q2B] {
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.Tetromino__block[quadrant=Q3A] {
  left: var(--tetromino-block-size);
  top: var(--tetromino-block-size);
}

.Tetromino__block[quadrant=Q3B] {
  left: 0;
  top: var(--tetromino-block-size);
}

.Tetromino__block[quadrant=Q4A] {
  left: calc(var(--tetromino-block-size) * 2);
  top: var(--tetromino-block-size);
}

.Tetromino__block[quadrant=Q4B] {
  left: calc(var(--tetromino-block-size) * 3);
  top: var(--tetromino-block-size);
}
```

Comment: This doesn't answer your question directly but why not render each square block of the tetromino separately. 

Also you could use HTML canvas for building games rather than using HTML elements. (unless this is a challenge you've taken up)

Comment: THAT'S SUCH A BETTER IDEA ROFL @PranavNachnekar